# How to determine if integers are within a range and store into two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have an array called `$grades` which contains grades ranging from negative numbers to numbers over 100.

I need to put the negative grades and the grades over 100 into their own array and all the other numbers into their own array.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($grades); $i++) {
    if ($grades[$i] < 0 || $grades[$i] > 100) {
        $invalidGrades[] = $i;
    } else if ($grades[$i] >= 0 && $grades[$i] <= 100) {
        $validGrades[] = $i;
    }
}
```

This is the code I have so far. It appears to only be returning the numbers in the count instead of the values.

Comment: `$i` is your counter, you probably want to store `$grades[$i]` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be you want assign the grades using same index you can try this way

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($grades); $i++) {

      if ($grades[$i] < 0 || $grades[$i] > 100) {
          $invalidGrades[$i] =  $grades[$i];
      } else if ($grades[$i] >= 0 && $grades[$i] <= 100) {
          $validGrades[$i] = $grades[$i];
      }
}
```

or      if you want push  the value

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($grades); $i++) {

      if ($grades[$i] < 0 || $grades[$i] > 100) {
          $invalidGrades[] =  $grades[$i];
      } else if ($grades[$i] >= 0 && $grades[$i] <= 100) {
          $validGrades[] = $grades[$i];
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$grades = array(88,86,90,78,95,101,78,105,79,110);
$invalidGrades = array();
$validGrades = array();

foreach($grades as $grade) {
    if ($grade > 100 || $grade < 0) {
        array_push($invalidGrades, $grade);
    } else {
        array_push($validGrades, $grade);
    }
}

print "Grades";
print_r($grades);
print "invalidGrades";
print_r($invalidGrades);
print "validGrades";
print_r($validGrades);
```

You should get the following.

```
php54s test.php 
Content-type: text/html

GradesArray
(
    [0] => -1
    [1] => -4
    [2] => -10
    [3] => 88
    [4] => 86
    [5] => 90
    [6] => 78
    [7] => 95
    [8] => 101
    [9] => 78
    [10] => 105
    [11] => 79
    [12] => 110
)
invalidGradesArray
(
    [0] => -1
    [1] => -4
    [2] => -10
    [3] => 101
    [4] => 105
    [5] => 110
)
validGradesArray
(
    [0] => 88
    [1] => 86
    [2] => 90
    [3] => 78
    [4] => 95
    [5] => 78
    [6] => 79
)
```

Answer (score 0):

foreach is your best option here, try this:

```
//Some random grades
$grades = [1, -10, 90, 30, -3, 200, 300, 44];
$validGrades = array();
$inValidGrades = array();

foreach($grades as $grade){
  if($grade < 0 || $grade > 100){
    $inValidGrades[] = $grade;
  }else{
    $validGrades[] = $grade;
  }
}

//Test the output
echo "<pre>";
print_r($grades);
echo "<br>";
print_r($validGrades);
echo "<br>";
print_r($inValidGrades);
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => -10
    [2] => 90
    [3] => 30
    [4] => -3
    [5] => 200
    [6] => 300
    [7] => 44
)

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 90
    [2] => 30
    [3] => 44
)

Array
(
    [0] => -10
    [1] => -3
    [2] => 200
    [3] => 300
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a simple `if-else` block.  The only choice about how to construct it comes down to if you want to use one condition or two in the `if` expression.

Method #1: ([Output Demo](https://3v4l.org/ItH2f)) ([Calculation Demo](https://3v4l.org/Bgt97)) "Single Condition"

```
$grades=array(-4,-1,0,1,6,10,70,99,100,101,105,110);
foreach($grades as $grade){
    if( ($grade+1)*(101-$grade) > 0 ){  // ($grade minus negative [lower limit])*([upper limit] plus $grad)
        $validGrades[] = $grade;
    }else{
        $invalidGrades[] = $grade;
    }
}
var_export($validGrades);
echo "\n---\n";
var_export($invalidGrades);
```

Method #2: ([Output Demo](https://3v4l.org/JJlVN)) "Double Condition"

```
$grades=array(-4,-1,0,1,6,10,70,99,100,101,105,110);
foreach($grades as $grade){
    if( $grade<0 || $grade>100 ){
        $validGrades[] = $grade;
    }else{
        $invalidGrades[] = $grade;
    }
}
var_export($validGrades);
echo "\n---\n";
var_export($invalidGrades);
```

Output (from either method)

```
array (
  0 => -4,
  1 => -1,
  2 => 101,
  3 => 105,
  4 => 110,
)
---
array (
  0 => 0,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 6,
  3 => 10,
  4 => 70,
  5 => 99,
  6 => 100,
)
```

***Notes:**

1. There will be an unnoticeable difference in efficiency between the two methods; this is purely demonstrative.
2. The "Double Condition" can also be written with the "And" logical operator (`&&`) as `if( $grade<=100 && $grade>=0 ){` with the same effect.
3. Because the *pass*/*fail* comparison is determined in the `if` expression, there is no need to use an `elseif` expression -- this would be redundant.
4. `foreach()` is a more appropriate construct to loop with versus `for` because calling the `count()` function is avoided.  This also prevents your coding error while trying to access the grades via their index.
5. Calling `array_push()` (as some other answers do) is unnecessary overhead -- not that it is actually going to impact your application.  I like to avoid function calls when possible.  Using `[]` syntax is the function-free alternative to `array_push()`.